# I have a problem tableViewCells is empty after parsing JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode

When I use simulator no any data in tableviewcell tableview is empty data is fully parsed and I can call any value of JSON. I don’t understand problem with my code because no any errors in terminal

For table view I created DailyWeatherViewCell.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

 class DailyWeatherViewCell:   UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var  dayLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherLabe: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var minMaxTempLabel: UILabel!

}
```

I parsed JSON by this way
ViewController.swift
     import UIKit
    import Foundation

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var cityNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var temperatureLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var weatherNowLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dailyWeatherTableView: UITableView!

var model: WeatherForecast?
var degreeSymbol = "º"


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    currentWeatherRequest()
    dailyWeatherTableView.delegate = self
    dailyWeatherTableView.dataSource = self

}
func currentWeatherRequest() {
let session = URLSession.shared
    let weatherURL = URL(string: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Atlanta,us&units=metric&APPID=c866a73a7aaaa3f2813b5930d028f514")!
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: weatherURL) { (data: Data?,response: URLResponse?,error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:\n\(error)")

        } else {
            if let jsonData = data {

                do {
                    let dataString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
          print("Daily weather data:\n\(dataString!)")
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let responseModel = try decoder.decode(WeatherForecast.self, from: jsonData)
              print(responseModel)
                    self.dailyWeatherTableView.reloadData()
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.cityNameLabel.text = responseModel.city.name
                        self.temperatureLabel.text = "\(String(describing: responseModel.list[0].main.temp))\(self.degreeSymbol)"
                        self.weatherNowLabel.text = String(describing: responseModel.list[0].weather[0].main)
                    }

                } catch let error {
                  print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            }else {
            print("Error: did not receive data")

        }
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()

}



public func tableView(_ tableView:         UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return self.model?.list.count ?? 0
   }
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell: DailyWeatherViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyWeatherViewCell", for: indexPath) as! DailyWeatherViewCell
   // let forecast: DailyForecast = (model?.ForecastforToday?[indexPath.row])
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval((model?.list[0].dt)! as Int))
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_US")
    dateFormatter.setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate("MMMMd")
    cell.dayLabel.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
    print(date)
    cell.minMaxTempLabel.text = "\(String(describing: model?.list[0].main.tempMin))\(self.degreeSymbol)\(String(describing: model?.list[0].main.tempMax))"
    print("\(String(describing: model?.list[0].main.tempMin))\(self.degreeSymbol)\(String(describing: model?.list[0].main.tempMax))")
    cell.weatherLabe.text = "\(String(describing: model?.list[0].weather[0].main))"
    print("\(String(describing: model?.list[0].weather[0].main))")
return cell
   }

}
```

I have this structure for parse JSON WeatherForecast data as Date in format: Month day(as May 23) also weather main should be put to dailyWeatherViewCell weatherLabel in next want to add systemIcon to it and minTemp and maxTemp to minMaxTempLabel

WeatherForecast.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
// MARK: - WeatherForecast
struct WeatherForecast: Codable {
let cod: String
let message, cnt: Int
let list: [List]
let city: City
}

// MARK: - City
struct City: Codable {
let id: Int
let name: String
let coord: Coord
let country: String
let population, timezone, sunrise, sunset: Int
}

// MARK: - Coord
struct Coord: Codable {
let lat, lon: Double
}

// MARK: - List
struct List: Codable {
let dt: Int
let main: MainClass
let weather: [Weather]
let clouds: Clouds
let wind: Wind
let sys: Sys
let dtTxt: String
let rain, snow: Rain?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, sys
    case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
    case rain, snow
}

}

// MARK: - Clouds
struct Clouds: Codable {
let all: Int
}

// MARK: - MainClass
struct MainClass: Codable {
let temp: Double
let feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
let tempKf: Double

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case temp = "temp"
    case feelsLike = "feels_like"
    case tempMin = "temp_min"
    case tempMax = "temp_max"
    case pressure
    case seaLevel = "sea_level"
    case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
    case humidity
    case tempKf = "temp_kf"
   }
}

// MARK: - Rain
struct Rain: Codable {
let the3H: Double

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case the3H = "3h"
}
}

// MARK: - Sys
struct Sys: Codable {
let pod: Pod
}

enum Pod: String, Codable {
case d = "d"
case n = "n"
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct Weather: Codable {
let id: Int
let main: MainEnum
let weatherDescription, icon: String

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case main
    case weatherDescription = "description"
    case icon
}


}

enum MainEnum: String, Codable {
case clear = "Clear"
case clouds = "Clouds"
case rain = "Rain"
case snow = "Snow"
}

// MARK: - Wind
struct Wind: Codable {
let speed: Double
let deg: Int
```

}
 I will be pleased for your help

Comment: Please assign the responseModel to model that is defined class level. Please move this self.dailyWeatherTableView.reloadData() call inside async { } as you are doing UI operation. If you want to debug this put breakpoint on the numberOfRowsInSection section check how many sections it returns if it doesn't return proper value then check the model class has values or not, If possible add WeatherForecast so we can check further.

Comment: WeatherForecast added

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First: you need to check UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource

in `viewDidLoad()`

```
   dailyWeatherTableView.delegate = self
   dailyWeatherTableView.dataSource = self
```

Second: assign decoding JSON Data to Your Model

So replace this 
`let responseModel = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: jsonData)`
with
`self.model  = try decoder.decode(Weather.self, from: jsonData)`

another solution you can assign `responseModel` for `model` 
so add this line `self.model = responseModel`

after assigning it, add `dailyWeatherTableView.reloadData()`

Finally, implement tableView `delegates, dataSource`

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model?.list.count ?? 0 // number of cells 
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyWeatherViewCell", for: indexPath) as? DailyWeatherViewCell else { return UITableViewCell() }
       // configure cell data 
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to reloaddata after assign model line , can you share implementation for delegate table view protocol

Comment: I did reloaddata as Sh_Khan recommended

Comment: Please, share screenshot for cellForRow func

Comment: That’s problem that I haven’t it can you write for example or as for my code needed?

Comment: @BrianAnderson please share your model?

Comment: added weatherForecast

Comment: @BrianAnderson you added weather not WeatherForecast

Comment: Please check again because that I have in my WeatherForecast.swift

Comment: Yeah so you should assign decode for model like `Weather.Self` not file name

Comment: now when I try to get temperature info to temperature label of swiftcontroller it put it as "Optional(-0,79)"

Comment: @BrianAnderson yes, add default value and please vote my answer